# application framework which support DOM parsing and cross-site ajax

Tags: ajax, web-applications, dom, gwt, web-frameworks

I want to make an application which can get different websites and extract data from their DOM. I intend to use XMLHttpRequest in Google Web Toolkit to make it. However, the XMLHttpRequest seems not to work because of the same-origin policy.

I wonder if there exist any other application framework which support DOM parsing and cross-site Ajax-like feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other domains you can only download JSON data. HTML or XML DOM won't be accessible due to security. In this case I see two options:

1. You will issue request to page origin server that will proxy the request to actual web server and therefore bypass the security restriction.
2. You can use some service to convert HTML or XML to JSON. I know just http://open.dapper.net/ that does that, but you need to first manually define records in the page, so it would work only with predefined set of pages, not URL that for instance a user is entering. But maybe there are XML to JSON converters that can convert any given URL. It wouldn't be difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

jquery and all various like dojo,YUI supports  cross browser requests through a hack.

Because of same origin policy you cannot make ajax requests to other domains, so to make such requests a commonly used hack http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

**Demo to describe the functionality**

Site-1's script

```
function MakeThirdPartyRequest()
{
     //make sure this domain returns pure json
     var Url="http://SomeOtherDomain.com"; 

      //now using javascript you add this TAG to body of html
     <script src="Url" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

    function jsonFromThirdParty(data)
{
 alert(data);
}
```

**Site 2 should return data in this format**

```
jsonFromThirdParty("hello iam data from other domain");
```

You can use some third party javascript libraries

Below is code to make cross domain ajax request

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url:'http://some_domain',
     dataType:'jsonp',
     type:'get',
     success:function(data)
    {
       alert(data);
    }
});
```